# flutter - not detecting adding AVM

Tags: android, flutter

As you can see from the gif, I have two AVDs set up. I can access them from the AVD Manager, however cannot add them to target selector.

I have restarted android development studio multiple times and still experiencing the same behaviour. Flutter doctor shows no error aside from no connected devices. I have the latest versions of all software as downloaded it today.
How do i overcome this behaviour?
[Gif detailing faulty adding behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5dNg.gif)

Comment: Find [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) from the command line and try `adb kill-server`, restart Android Studio, and try the emulator again.

Comment: also on my device this is not running as expected and I think you could file an issue on github. Even after adb kill-server and restart, I can start the emulator with Android Studio, but afterwards have to select a new entry "Android SDK built for x86" in the device-selector to actually start the app on the emulator. Maybe this is still a solution for you to get running.